# Stereoisomerism in 1,2-cyclobutanediol

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, cis-trans-isomerism

For 1,2-cyclobutanediol, it's given in my book that it has 3 stereo isomers.
Here's the passage:

[image]

My questions:

1. How can it have stereo-isomers?
2. What will the meso compounds look like?

Answer (score 11):

These two isomers are enantiomers, i.e. mirror images, of each other:

$\hspace{50 mm}$[image: Chiral]

This one has a plane of symmetry through the molecule and is therefore *meso*:

$\hspace{60 mm}$[image: Meso]